# Iterate over a text file having hyphenated three different fields on each line and return third field to a query matching the first two?

Tags: python, twitter, hyphenation

I have a text file with about 100 lines of data arranged in this order:

```
Aesop – Aesop’s Fables – example.com
Sherwood – Winesburg – example.com
Lysistrata – Holyland – example.com
Isaac – Nightfall – example.com
Asimov – The Foundation Trilogy – link to mp3
```

I want to write a Twitter bot that will iterate over the text file line by line, search tweets containing the first two fields, viz. author's name and book, and if either of the fields on **each line** match the tweet, reply to the tweet with the third field, i.e the link to the mp3. How do I do it efficiently using **Python** 3? If there is a much faster way, please tell.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. Which part in particular are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Thank you for the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

tweet = "Some Tweet including Asimov #Example"

with open("so_textfile_reading.txt", "r") as infile:
    # be aware you are not using a standard minus (HYPHEN-MINUS)
    # in your file to separate the entries, but dashes (EN-DASH)
    entries = [line.strip().split(" – ") for line in infile]
    for author, book, link in entries:
        if (author in tweet) or (book in tweet):
            # Create reply here
            print(link)
```

You can iterate through all lines of the file. Strip them of any white spaces, line breaks etc. and then split them up on the `-` to get tuples of author, book and link. You have to be careful about the characters in the split though (see comment in code).

Then you just have to check if either the author or the book occur in your tweet's text. Note that multiple hits could occur per tweet so you would have to collect hits (for example in a list) and create a reply after you visited all 100 entries.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the code and the helpful explanation. I respect you.